# ¿Cómo conseguir el tamaño de un texto con elementbytagname - JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una lista con etiquetas p dentro. Quiero conseguir el tamaño de cada texto y luego recortarlo. Tengo esto:

```
<script>
    var text;
    for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName("p").length;i++){
      console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].length+ "");
      if(text[i].length > 12) {
          text[i] = text[i].substring(0,10)+"...";
      }
    }
</script>
```

El problema es que me da undefined. También tenía otra duda. ¿Dónde debería colocar este trozo de código, dentro del head o al final del body? ¿Sería mejor hacerlo con jQuery?

Comment: el problema es que la variable `text` no la estás inicializando .. quieres un: `var text = document.getElementsByTagName("p")`?

Comment: @lois6b Lo que quiero es que la variable text almacene el tamaño de cada texto

Comment: Entonces `text` no es un nombre muy correcto. Pero la cosa es que la funcion `getElementsByTagName("p")` devuelve un array con los elementos cuya etiqueta sea esa. pero tienes que seleccionar qué quieres... el texto dentro de `<p>` se obtiene con `innerHTML`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basándome en tu ejemplo:

```js
var text;
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("p").length + ' Elmentos P ');

for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("p").length ; i++) {
  console.log(i+1);
  console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i]);
  console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].textContent.length);
  document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].textContent = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].textContent.substring(0,12) + "...";
}
```

```html
<p>1 Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo
</p>
<p>2 Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo
</p>
<p>3 Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo
</p>
<p>
4 Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo
</p>
<p>
5  Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo
</p>
<p>
6 Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo
</p>
<p>7 0123456789</p>
```

Sobre `jQuery` claro que seria mas fácil si lo utilizaras.

Ejemplo con jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Llamo la fución each de jquery y le mando como parametro todos los objetos P $("p")
  $.each($("p"),function(indice, valor){
    //console.log(indice);    
    //console.log(valor);
    //This es el objeto actual, el P del ciclo que corresponda
    //la propiedad .text modifica el texto del P, obtiene y modifica
    $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0,12) + "...");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>1 Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo
</p>
<p>2 Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo
</p>
<p>3 Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo
</p>
<p>
4 Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo
</p>
<p>
5  Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo
</p>
<p>
6 Parrafo ejemplo Parrafo ejemplo
</p>
<p>7 0123456789</p>
```

Comment: Si das el visto bueno, es aconsejable dar un punto positivo también @AdrianRodriguez  aunque no es obligatorio es una forma de dar puntos positivos a quienes responden las preguntas, y esto mejora la experiencia de usuario en el sitio de SOes.

Comment: @MarcLemien el OP no recibirá tu notificación, pues no publicó ninguna comentario en esta publicación :/

Comment: No importa, a quien lo lea es una buena practica que muchos no hacen, quien lo lea le servirá.

Comment: @MarcLemien por si acaso, [How do comment `@replies` work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/209901), pues esta respuesta tuya la vi por casualidad.

Answer (score 5):

Para que la variable `texto` almacene el tamaño, has crear una variable (`elementos` por ejemplo) que recoja el array que devuelve la funcion `getElementsByTagName("p")`

Despues inicializas `textos` como un array con numero de elementos igual al numero de elementos obtenidos.

Despues iteras como hacías, pero no puedes hacer un `.lenght` directamente sino que tienes que acceder a la propiedad `innerHTML` que recoge el texto entre las etiquetas `<p>` y  `</p>`

Dentro del `if` donde compruebas si es `>12` has de poner el `elementos[i].innerHTML` en la parte izq de la asignación para cambiar su contenido. (aunque no entiendo por qué la comprobación pones `12` y en el `substring` pones `10`)

```
<script>
    var elementos= document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var textos =  new Array (elementos.length);
    for(var i=0;i<elementos.length;i++){
        console.log(elementos[i].innerHTML.length+ "");
        textos[i] = elementos[i].innerHTML.length;
        if(elementos[i].innerHTML.length > 12) {
            elementos[i].innerHTML = elementos[i].innerHTML.substring(0,10)+"...";
        }
     }
</script>
```

```js
    var elementos= document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var textos =  new Array (elementos.length);
    for(var i=0;i<elementos.length;i++){
      console.log(elementos[i].innerHTML.length+ "");
      textos[i] = elementos[i].innerHTML.length;
      if(elementos[i].innerHTML.length > 12) {
          elementos[i].innerHTML = elementos[i].innerHTML.substring(0,10)+"...";
      }

    }
```

```html
<p>Probando la funcion javascript</p>
<p>Probando la funcion javascript con distintas longitudes</p>
<p>Probando javascript</p>
<p>Probando la funcion</p>
<p>Probando la funcion javascript otra vez</p>
```

Respecto a donde ponerlo, puedes meter esto en una funcion que se llame en el evento `onLoad`